# What is the difference of Firebase authentication custom claims and Firestore document with no write access?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm looking for the difference between Firebase authentication with custom claims and a private Firestore document for each user with no write permissions.

The use case I am facing is a SaaS solution with 3 stripe plans. Each stripe plans has different properties. A user should be restricted to the plan they are subscribe to.

The only difference I see is that custom claims only require on call to Firebase while a document in Firestore would require 2 (auth + get user private data).

Are there any other differences I'm missing?

Comment: It's really not clear to me what you're trying to compare here.  Also not clear to me how Cloud Functions is related, since you tagged it that way.

Comment: @doug The 2 options I wanted compare are in answer of Frank. In case of having the payment plan in a non-writeable document I'd require two request to get the data, 3 including auth. One to get the auth user, second to get the stripe plan and a third to user data based on the plan. I was curious if a Cloud Function for the getting both the stripe plan and the user data would be a good idea as it would be just one call? From a performance perspective.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to compare two security models:

1. Store the payment plan information in a custom claim in the user's token.
2. Store the payment plan in a non-writeable document in Firestore.

Some changes that come to mind:

1. As you say the second option will require an extra read operation whenever the security rules need to be validated.
2. Storing the information in the token makes each request from the user bigger, since the claim is in their token. So it uses more bandwidth.

But probably the most important one for making up you mind:

3. A custom claim may not be immediately available on the client, since it depends on the token being refreshed, which may take up to an hour. The information in the database on the other hands is up to date as soon as you write it.

For more good tips around this, have a look at the video [Five tips to secure your app](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pvLkkLjHdkw).

Comment: Thanks. Totally on point. In the case of custom claim I have one question left for. Can I force reset the user token or would the onAuthStateChanged be triggered after the custom claims are updated? I'm just want to ensure front end sync when the subscription plan is updated! @frank

Comment: You can force a token refresh from the client, but the exact call of course depends on the platform. But it's a bit involved, which is why most developers store this more quick status transition information in the database, and only use custom claims for things like "this use is an admin" type things. Watch the linked video for an explanation of that.